# How to resend failed SMS in bulk

Tags: sms, send, twilio

Twillio failed 150 SMS due to lack of funds in the middle of a campaign. Is there a way to resend those 150 messages in bulk? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any sort of message queue?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a queue on your side, the easiest way is to use the API to find the list and resend as appropriate:

- You can use the SMS Messages List Resource - http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms#list - to get a list of messages within a certain date range from a certain number.
- From there, you'll get back a list which you can iterate over. For each of those, check the "status" parameter for the "failed" value - http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms#sms-status-values
- I would recommend making a list of those, looking at them yourself to make sure the numbers are what you expect and then reload them send via your normal means.

On another front, we have auto-recharging specifically to prevent scenarios specifically like this. If that's not turned on, you should enable it so this doesn't happen again.

*Disclosure: Twilio Employee here*